# Class holding collection of other class

Tags: design, c++, c++11

I have a `class Item`. Then another `class ItemCollection` holds `std::map<int,Item> item_collection_`. The reason to create the `class ItemCollection` is if I want to do something with collection of type_a I can delegate that task to `class ItemCollection`. For me this seems normal way of doing tasks on those collection of items.

1. Does this kind of behavior occur regularly in software design (I have
   regularly encountered this problem)?
2. Is this the correct way to approach the problem?
3. Is there name given to this kind of design problem?
4. I don't want others to modify the  collection of item I hold. Any
   modification to Item has to go through `class ItemCollection`. Do
   you think keeping this restriction make the design simple or will it
   make more complex? Thats why I only have `const Item &GetItem(int id)`.
5. I choose map instead of vector because of function like
   `ClassifyItemsAs`. Map helped me find the item by id faster. If I
   had `vector` then search would have been `Big O of N`, where as in
   `std::map` its `Big O of LogN`.

.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

enum class Classify { no_type, type_a, type_b, type_c };

class Item {
 public:
  Item(int id, double val) : id_(id), value_(val) {}
  int GetID() const { return id_; }
  double GetValue() const { return value_; }
  Classify GetType() const { return type_; }
  void SetType(Classify type) { type_ = type; }

 private:
  int id_;
  double value_;
  Classify type_{Classify::no_type};
};

class ItemCollection {
 public:
  void AddItem(Item arg) {
    item_collection_.insert(std::make_pair(arg.GetID(), arg));
  }
  // Dont know if this is necessary because all the modification should go
  // through this class.
  const Item &GetItem(int id) const { return item_collection_.at(id); }
  // should I make it const reference by having vector of each type stored
  // separately then do GetItemOfTypeA(),GetItemOfTypeB() ...
  std::vector<Item> GetItemOfType(Classify type) const {
    std::vector<Item> item_coll;
    for (const auto &it : item_collection_) {
      if (it.second.GetType() == type){
        item_coll.push_back(it.second);
      }
    }
    return item_coll;
  }
  void ClassifyItemsAs(Classify type, const std::vector<int> &item_ids) {
    for (auto &id : item_ids) {
      item_collection_.at(id).SetType(type);
    }
  }

  void PrintItem(Classify type) const {
    for (const auto &item : GetItemOfType(type)) {
      std::cout << item.GetID() << " : " << item.GetValue() << std::endl;
    }
  }

 private:
  std::map<int, Item> item_collection_;
};

int main() {
  ItemCollection item_coll;
  Item item1(5, 0.1);
  Item item2(16, 0.1);
  Item item3(0, 0.1);
  Item item4(29, 0.1);
  item_coll.AddItem(item1);
  item_coll.AddItem(item2);
  item_coll.AddItem(item3);
  item_coll.AddItem(item4);

  std::vector<int> ids = {5, 16};
  // If I did not have that class then I would have to write all code in main
  // and main would look dirty.
  item_coll.ClassifyItemsAs(Classify::type_a, ids);
  item_coll.PrintItem(Classify::type_a);
}
```

Comment: "*if I want to do something with collection of type_a I can delegate that task to class ItemCollection.*" But it won't be. It will be a collection of `Item`. That's all it will ever be.

Comment: but didn't function `void ClassifyItemsAs(Classify type, const std::vector<int> &item_ids)` just achieved that?  It did something with collection of type Classify (In example I use `type_a` but work any `enum class Classify`).

Comment: No, it just stores a different enumeration value in the object. That doesn't change the *type* of anything. Not in the C++ sense of that word, at any rate; `Item` is the type stored in your container. Always.

Comment: I am little confused. Then who is to handle task on modifying, gathering, adding, generate statistics on the collection of the Items, etc. What would that class look like? Isn't `class ItemCollection` supposed to do that. I know `class ItemCollection` is `collection of Item (In my case map of Item)` but in my case it also handle tasks that I delegate (modifying, gathering, adding, generate statistics on the collection of the Items, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a reasonable thing to do. If you were literally duplicating the interface of std::map then it would have been questionable, but still might have been valid if the behaviors of individual functions were slightly different. If there were to be any point of concern, then it would be `std::vector<Item> GetItemOfType(Classify type)` : given that all modifications are supposed to happen through the collection type, I'd suggest considering the possibility of calculating (and recalculating) the return value of that function ahead of time, and storing it in another map.

As for what this pattern is called, it's called an "object". Normally objects are defined in terms of inheritance & all sorts of other details that breaks the definition every time someone devises a new variant of object, but my own definition is this:

```
An object is a grouping of zero or more pieces of data, and zero or more sets of instructions, that behave as a single, contiguous thing
```

Let's use a car as an example: if you intended it to be possible to *remove* fuel from the car, as well as add it, then representing the fuel with a publicly visible variable in a C++ class would comply with that class being an object or object type. However, if either adding or removing fuel was supposed to not be possible, or the speed at which fuel was added was supposed to be restricted, then it would prevent that class from being a proper object or object type, because the class would not be able to enforce the object's behavioral rules, thus exposing a "seam" in the object where it is no longer a single thing but instead several.

Similarly, if a car is only supposed to have two speeds, "move" and "stay", then exposing a speed variable publicly is fine. If it's supposed to show acceleration, then you need to hide the speed variable, and instead expose an acceleration variable. If you want to somehow model the movement of a foot on an accelerator pedal, then you'll want to either expose a "foot pressure" variable, or even jump straight to a function. The model that you *have to* follow depends purely on what rules your car is supposed to follow: if you properly enforce those rules, then you've created an object, otherwise you haven't.

Your ItemCollection appears to follow a self-consistent set of rules, so that means it's an actual object.

Comment: Regarding std::vector<Item> GetItemOfType(Classify type) I like your idea of storing as map but did u mean map as std::map<Classify, std::vector<Item>> or std::map<Classify, std::vector<int>>(To represent id of Item I used int)? Because if we do std::map<Classify, std::vector<Item>> then we are having two copies aren't we?

Comment: Also, is there something called object pattern or did u mean Type Object?

Comment: Probably std::map<Classify, std::vector< std::map<int, Item>::const_iterator >>, though you could go with the ints instead of iterators.

Comment: As for "object", I mean that literally what you've done is create a true & proper object, and that this is a reasonable thing to do. If you really feel the need to classify it as a pattern, then I suppose I'd go with "container" or "collection". That you are using std::map internally is only an implementation detail, and should otherwise be ignored.

Comment: Is object design pattern similar to composite design pattern I asked because they do sound similar. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/composite-design-pattern/

Comment: Also did u understood what  @Nicol Bolas was talking about `ItemCollection 
 being collection of Item. That's all it will ever be` But for me `ItemColection` not just ` collection of Item`,  its also class that accomplices certain tasks eg `ClassifyItemsAs, PrintItem` etc

Comment: Stop worrying about patterns. At any rate, this is absolutely NOT a composite patterned object. This could be considered a https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Structural_Patterns#Facade Facade patterned object.

Comment: As for Nicol Bolas, I have no idea what "But it won't be." was even supposed to mean in that context. Whether ItemCollection is "just" a collection of Item instances doesn't matter though. What matters is that the functionality isn't a straight duplication of std::map<>, everything else is unimportant.